# removing comma from object

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am using localStorage to store a list of values from an array.  Since I can only bring it over as a string into a new session I have to save it as a string.

I want to print each value on a new line but since the array is converted into a string and then an object printing on a new line carries over the commas.  I want to simply print each item on a new line without a comma inside p tags.  I have tried joining and splitting but it did not work.  Any thoughts anyone?  I am sure there is a super simple solution, but it eludes me.

I have tried to also include a break tag but it does not remove the comma.

As you can see, I can get the item to print on a new line by adding p tags but the comma comes along, how do i remove it?

[image]

My code:

```
var theLIst = document.getElementById('list');
var resetNotify = document.getElementById('reset-message');
var st = window.localStorage;
var nameArray = [];

theLIst.innerHTML = JSON.parse(st.getItem('names'));

function addName() {

    resetNotify.innerHTML = '';
    var name = document.getElementById('names');
    nameArray = JSON.parse(st.getItem('names'));


    if ( nameArray != null) {
        nameArray.join('');
        nameArray.push("<p>" + name.value + "</p>");

    } else {
        console.log('The Array has been purged. Resetting.')
        nameArray = [];
        nameArray.push("<p>" + name.value + "</p>");

    }

    st.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(nameArray));
    console.log(nameArray);
    name.value = '';
    theLIst.innerHTML = JSON.parse(st.getItem('names'));
}

function clearArray() {
    st.clear();
    nameArray = [];
    console.log(nameArray);
    theLIst.innerHTML = '';
    resetNotify.innerHTML = 'Array has been purged.';
}
```

Comment: Add a sample object stored in localStorage.

Comment: You should do this: `st.setItem("names", nameArray.join(""))` so that your array is not auto-casted to a string after JSON.parse with `theLIst.innerHTML = JSON.parse(st.getItem('names'))`.

Comment: i cannot save it to localstorage if i do that.

Comment: Or you could do this: `JSON.parse(st.getItem('names')).join("")`;

Comment: getting .join() is not a function

Comment: I guess some random ideas: `setItem('names', JSON.stringify(nameArray.join(' '));` and when parsing, `split(' ');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (albeit a slightly hacky one).  So as it turns out, I needed to simply take my localStorage object and turn it into an array using Array.from().  I had to do this because I was not able to use .join(), .split() etc, methods that would have made my life a lot easier!

I took the new value processed it independently from the array where I stored my entries.  This allowed me to .join('') the values

(forgive the janky code)

My code:

```
var theLIst = document.getElementById('list');
var resetNotify = document.getElementById('reset-message');
var recordCounter = document.getElementById('record-counter');
var st = window.localStorage;
var entry = st.clickcount;
var nameArray = [];
var newArr;

theLIst.innerHTML = st.getItem('names').replace(/[\[\],"]+/g,'');

function addName() {

    resetNotify.innerHTML = '';

    var name = document.getElementById('names');
    nameArray = JSON.parse(st.getItem('names'));
    entry = Number(entry)+1;
    newArr = makeArr(nameArray);

    if ( nameArray != null) {
       nameArray.push("<p class='name-entry'>"+name.value+"</p>");

    } else {
        nameArray = [];
        nameArray.push("<p class='name-entry'>"+name.value+"</p>");

    }

    st.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(nameArray));
    name.value = '';

    if (!newArr[0]) {
        entry = 1;
        theLIst.innerHTML = nameArray;
        recordCounter.innerHTML = "Records: " + entry;
    } else {
        theLIst.innerHTML = newArr[0].join('');
        recordCounter.innerHTML = "Records: " + entry;
    }
    JSON.parse(st.getItem('names'));    
}

function makeArr() {
    return Array.from(arguments);
}

function clearArray() {
    st.clear();
    nameArray = [];
    console.log(nameArray);
    theLIst.innerHTML = '';
    resetNotify.innerHTML = 'Array has been purged.';
}
```

I figured out that I did not have a way around dealing with the fact that I am working with a string every time I refresh my browser so I use some regex to eliminate the extra characters so I could display my list on refresh, this has worked for me.

```
theLIst.innerHTML = st.getItem('names').replace(/[\[\],"]+/g,'');
```

This returned a list of clean entries to my html.  I also added a records counter to keep track of my entries.[image]

Thanks for your input everyone! I hope this is helpful to someone.